# Why did Kamsa not kill Devaki or her husband and still make them stay in the same cell?

Tags: puranas, krishna

As per Puranas, when Kamsa knew his sister, Devaki’s son will kill him, why did he not kill Devaki or her husband; and why did he **still** make them live together in the same cell?

Comment: I don't think that the above post answers OP's main question "why did he not kill Devaki or Husband"

Comment: I can't understand why people are rushing to close a question as opinion based. Scripture has explanation and a nice answer has been provided.

Comment: Let’s call it Hari Maya that it didn’t occur to Kamsa? The lord knew that six sons will be destroyed by Kamsa (due to a curse by Hiranyakashipu to those six Danava sons of Kalanemi in their previous birth [Harivamsa Purana]). Hence the only way for the curse to be fulfilled and Shri Hari to deliver them was if Devaki an Vasudeva were allowed union. Then again, Kamsa was arrogant and he thought he could control the child. Why He didn’t kill Vasudeva and Devaki- which has been described by Swift Pushkar below. The Hari Maya part is my speculation because Puranas talk nothing of it.

Comment: @hanugm I’ve edited the question a little to make it sound less opinion based. and it seems the close vote has been retracted by whoever read yourself message lol. Hanseinmithun, I hope the editing is fine. Else you can revert back to your original.

Comment: @Archit Oh nice....

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/311/why-didnt-kamsa-keep-vasudeva-and-devaki-in-separate-cells

Comment: The question suggested above for this question is deviating the intention. My ask is why he did not kill Devaki or Vasudev and still permitted them to live in the same cell like a fool. If i was Kamsa, i would have not done that mistake. Also when Akashavani mentioned that 8th son will kill, why the hell he kill 7 sons of his lovely sister? Also why the hell Vasudev produced so many kids knowing Kamsa will kill all his kids. It Just looks so foolish to me...

Comment: As I said Hari Maya! The other kids were killed because of Narada instigating Kamsa (Srimad Bhagavatham) that they were devatas being born and there was a ploy to kill Kamsa. Therefore, six children were killed- As I said they were killed because they had been cursed so. And as far as children go, many of the kings at that time had many children. For examples why did Veda Vyasa split the flesh blob into a 100 children? Why not 3-4?. Vasudeva thought that either Kamsa May die before only or something of fate (Srimad Bhagavat) so at least he can save his wife. Same cell = Hari Maya

Comment: @Hansiemithun Ofcourse he is a fool... Please read the words of akasha-vani once... https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/1/34/

Comment: @hanugm -I  think the Akashwani   deliberately  called him foolish to provoke him to  offend devaki.So as to rest of the plan come true. See the commentary below the shloka you linked.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar yeah, he is not innocent.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/311/why-didnt-kamsa-keep-vasudeva-and-devaki-in-separate-cells   somehow i marked wrong question as duplicate. This is what i actually meant

Comment: Kalanemi is kamsa previous birth he cursed his sons to be born again and killed in his hand in order to fulfill the curse sons of kalanemi born to vasudeva and devaki and killed by kamsa who is kalanemi in previous birth this is deva guhya known to devatha, vasudeva and devaki

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why did he not kill Devaki or Husband and yet made them live together in the same cell?

**Kamsa did tried and was ready to kill Devaki** at the time when the voice from the sky warned him about his death from the hands of Devakis eighth son . But Vasudeva pacified him with a promise that he will hand over all their sons to kamsa afterwards and hense Kaṁsa agreed to the logical arguments of Vasudeva, and, having full faith in Vasudeva’s words, he refrained from killing his sister. The answer is given in [**Shrimad Bhagvata Purana**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/1/)-Canto 10- Chapter 1.

---

Brief story-

After their marriage Vasudeva and devaki the sister of kamsa were departing towards their home. kamsa brother-in-law of Vasudeva   driving their chariot who was   accompanying them along the way. At that time a voice from the sky  as a omen said to kamsa that eighth son from womb of   Devaki shall slay you.
kamsa who was already  awicked sinful fellow thus being thus warned got ready to kill his own sister by  holding of his sister’s hair with his left hand and took up his sword in right.

> इत्युक्त: स खल: पापो भोजानां कुलपांसन: ।
>  भगिनीं हन्तुमारब्धं
> खड्‍गपाणि: कचेऽग्रहीत् ॥ [**SB 10.1. 35**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/1/35/) ॥
>
> Kamsa was a condemned personality in the Bhoja dynasty because he was
> envious and sinful. Therefore, upon hearing this omen from the sky, he
> caught hold of his sister’s hair with his left hand and took up his
> sword with his right hand to sever her head from her body.

But then Vasudeva the newly wedded husband of Devaki ,  intending  to gain the favor of wicked kamsa started  to  pacify him.

> श्रीवसुदेव उवाच
>  श्लाघनीयगुण: शूरैर्भवान् भोजयशस्कर: । 
> स कथं
> भगिनीं हन्यात् स्त्रियमुद्वाहपर्वणि ॥   [**SB 10.1.37**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/1/37/) ॥
>
> Vasudeva said: My dear brother-in-law Kaṁsa, you are the pride of your
> family, the Bhoja dynasty, and great heroes praise your qualities. How
> could such a qualified person as you kill a woman, your own sister,
> especially on the occasion of her marriage?

But since kamsa was Rakkshasa and was  fiercely cruel  he could be neither pacified nor terrified by the good instructions given by Vasudeva. He did not care about the results of sinful activities, either in this life or in the next and was determined to kill his sister Devaki.

Then in last resort Vasudeva in order to end the hostility promised to handover all their sons to Kamsa.  Kaṁsa agreed to the logical arguments of Vasudeva, and, having full faith in Vasudeva’s words, he refrained from killing his sister.

> श्रीवसुदेव उवाच
>  न ह्यस्यास्ते भयं सौम्य यद् वैसाहाशरीरवाक् ।
>
> पुत्रान् समर्पयिष्येऽस्या यतस्ते भयमुत्थितम् ॥ 54 ॥
> स्वसुर्वधान्निववृते कंसस्तद्वाक्यसारवित् । 
>  वसुदेवोऽपि तं प्रीत:
> प्रशस्य प्राविशद् गृहम् ॥ [**SB 10.1.54 -55**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/1/54/) ॥
>
> Vasudeva said: O best of the sober, you have nothing to fear from your
> sister Devakī because of what you have heard from the unseen omen. The
> cause of death will be her sons. Therefore I promise that when she
> gives birth to the sons from whom your fear has arisen, I shall
> deliver them all unto your hands.
>
> Śrīla Śukadeva Gosvāmī continued: Kaṁsa agreed to the logical
> arguments of Vasudeva, and, having full faith in Vasudeva’s words, he
> refrained from killing his sister. Vasudeva, being pleased with Kaṁsa,
> pacified him further and entered his own house.

---

So kamsa was not so foolish but since his danger was not  Vasudeva nor Devaki nor even the  first  seven sons  but the  eighth son only . So he decided not to kill any of them but their sons only he then kept both of them in chains and killed every new-born child of them (seven of them). Kamsa kept full faith in Vasudeva’s words that they will give all their children to Kamsa did not kill them.

Comment: In that case, he could have just waited and killed 8th son. Why he killed all 7 sons of his lovely sister? Why was he killing every kid in the town? Also why Vasudev produced so many kids, knowingly that Kamsa will kill each one...

Comment: "Why he killed all 7 sons" the answer is also given in verse 65-66. After knowing that Vishnu will going to kill him as eighth son of devaki he started fearing Vishnu and  desperately killed all 7 children.

<b>Suspecting each of the children to be Viṣṇu, Kaṁsa killed them one after another because of the prophecy that Viṣṇu would kill him<b>

https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/1/65-66/

Comment: If i was Kamsa, i would have definetely not kept them in the same cell. And when i have that much love towards Devaki, atleast i would have killed Vasudev and arranged a second marriage of Devaki to someother King or Rakshasa... Hence i raised this question as he is a fool being such moster Rakshasa

Comment: See Kamsa didn't wanted to keep them in jail as such he just wanted to make sure that every child born to them that same child is handed over to him especially the 8th one. It was not possible without keeping them in his custody under watchfulness of gards.